# MySQL insert and update triggers

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

I have a general question about triggers in MySQL. I'm trying to write a trigger, but i'm not sure when it will be triggered, the table is constantly updated using `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` queries (mostly the update part), so which event (insert or update) will be triggered? Or it can trigger both events depending on which part will take effect?

Thanks

Comment: It's really RTFM question - why do not simply read that in [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You can define trigger for different events:

- before insert
- after insert
- before update
- after update

Example

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_your_table AFTER INSERT ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    ....
END
$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of that. But will this trigger in your example will work on a table which is affected by a query with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part?

Comment: When a table has an update or insert the trigger runs, no matter how the update/insert was started.